# Force simulated location to be fixed in XCode 6.4

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-location

Hi I am trying to simulate the location of my iOS simulator with my app using this feature.

[image: Simulate location]

The app fetches the location like this

```
var currentLocation: CLLocation?
if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse || CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedAlways) {
    currentLocation = manager.location
}
```

The problem is that this code is executed when the app starts up and then the simulated location is always reset to nothing. Can I force this location to be set to the same value after the app is started again through XCode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit the scheme of your application, go to the *Run* phase, click on the *Options* tab, and check the box, *Allow Location Simulation*.  You can then select what the default simulated location should be.

[image]

As a side note, you can add GPX files to your project for custom simulated locations, like your office, home, or favorite place to eat and these, too, will be selectable as a location to simulate.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Is this then the preferred way to simulate location instead of doing it in the simulator (Debug > Location)?

Comment: @pallzoltan  Not sure what you mean by 'preferred'.  Adding a GPX file allows quick movement to a predetermined location, rather than having to enter specific GPS coordinates to where you want to be.  The simulator could be considered 'preferred' if you're wanting to simulate specific scenarios like movement.

Comment: The question I'm confronting is whether I should simulate location form Xcode or from the Device Simulator.

Comment: @pallzoltan if you're just needing a point on a map, I'd go with Xcode. If you need to simulate travel, use the simulator. Xcode for points would be preferred because you can put those gpx files under version control and have a repeatable--and quick--way to easily jump to different locations in a map.